# How to sort an array of objects with dynamic property?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of objects and the sorting will be done based on property which will be dynamic

I have an array

```
const fruitDetails = [
  {item: "Berry", qty: "651042446", stockDate: "2021-09-20"},
  {item: "Apple", qty: "23222", stockDate: "2023-08-10"},
  {item: "Kiwi", qty: "132345", stockDate: "2022-10-23"}
];
```

Now the sorting could be of on item, qty or stockDate

A function to sort this array of objects with dynamic property

```
function sortedData(column) {
  return fruitDetails.sort((a, b) => {
     if (a[column].toLowerCase() > b[column].toLowerCase()) {
       return 1;
     }
     if (a[column].toLowerCase() < b[column].toLowerCase()) {
       return -1;
     }
     return 0;
  });
}


console.log(sortedData("item"));
console.log(sortedData("qty"));
console.log(sortedData("stockDate"));
```

If you check the console output the sorted value for item and stockDate is correct but the qty sorted value is incorrect.

This is the console output for qty:

```
[{
  item: "Kiwi",
  qty: "132345",
  stockDate: "2022-10-23"
}, {
  item: "Apple",
  qty: "23222",
  stockDate: "2023-08-10"
}, {
  item: "Berry",
  qty: "651042446",
  stockDate: "2021-09-20"
}]
```

The qty value 23222 is smaller than the 132345 so Apple should be 1st, Kiwi 2nd and Berry 3rd.

I am adding the [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/Ln7u5zqb/) for reference.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong here, thank you :)

Comment: Those are string values. If you want to compare them as numbers, they should either be numbers in the data structure or else you'll have to convert them to numbers when comparing.

Comment: why don't you use numbers type or check values as numbers ?

Comment: @Pointy Anyway I can change the same function to make it work for string and number

Comment: You would have to code it to say this column is a number and convert it. so do something like `sortedData("qty", "number")`  and in the function add logic to convert it to a number and compare.

Comment: @epascarello I won't be able to find if the property value is number or not. This is completely dynamic

Comment: SO then you need to get creative in the code and add detections if it is a number or a date. That would be basic reg exps.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const fruitDetails = [{
    item: "Berry",
    qty: "651042446",
    stockDate: "2021-09-20"
  },
  {
    item: "Apple",
    qty: "23222",
    stockDate: "2023-08-10"
  },
  {
    item: "Kiwi",
    qty: "132345",
    stockDate: "2022-10-23"
  }
];

function filters(key) {
  return fruitDetails.sort((a, b) => {
    if (key === 'item') {
      return a[key].localeCompare(b[key])
    } else if (key === 'qty') {
      return a[key] - (b[key]);
    } else if (key === 'stockDate') {
      return new Date(a[key]) - new Date((b[key]));
    }
  })
}
console.log(filters("item"));
console.log(filters("qty"));
console.log(filters("stockDate"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions to test for numbers, then you would subtract the numbers (converted from strings) as you normally would when sorting numbers. Otherwise use the `String#localCompare` method as follows; strings and "date strings" in the format provided should sort fine with `.localeCompare()`:

```js
const fruitDetails = [
  {item: "Berry", qty: "651042446", stockDate: "2021-09-20"},
  {item: "Apple", qty: "23222", stockDate: "2023-08-10"},
  {item: "Kiwi", qty: "132345", stockDate: "2022-10-23"}
];

function sortedData(column) { //ascending order
  return fruitDetails.sort((a, b) => {
     const numRe = /^[0-9]*$/;
     if (numRe.test(a[column]) && numRe.test(b[column])) {
         return +a[column] - +b[column];
     } else {
         return a[column].localeCompare(b[column]);
     }
  });
}


console.log(sortedData("item"));
console.log(sortedData("qty"));
console.log(sortedData("stockDate"));
```